# why is the qooxdoo generator throwing the error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: qooxdoo

When I run the qooxdoo generator on my source, I get the error:

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

What about my source code is causing this:

```
/* ************************************************************************

   Copyright:

   License:

   Authors:

   ************************************************************************ */

/* ************************************************************************

   #asset(first/*)

   ************************************************************************ */

/**
 * This is the main application class of your custom application "first"
 */
qx.Class.define("first.Application", {

    extend : qx.application.Standalone,
    members : {

    main : function() {
        // Call super class
        this.base(arguments);

        // Enable logging in debug variant
        if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug")) {
        // support native logging capabilities, e.g. Firebug for Firefox
        qx.log.appender.Native;
        // support additional cross-browser console. Press F7 to toggle visibility
        qx.log.appender.Console;
        }

        var layout = new qx.ui.layout.Grid(9, 5);

        var label_f = new qx.ui.basic.Label("fahrenheit");
        var label_c = new qx.ui.basic.Label("celsius");
        var tf_f = new qx.ui.form.TextField();
        var tf_c = new qx.ui.form.TextField();

        var button_f = new qx.ui.form.Button("F->C");
        var button_c = new qx.ui.form.Button("C->F");

        // Document is the application root
        var doc = this.getRoot();
        doc.setLayout(layout);

        // Add button to document at fixed coordinates
        doc.add(label_f, {row: 0, column: 0});

    }

    }
}
           );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python exception. Your JavaScript seems fine, I got it running without problems. Can you please do the following:

- state how you are running the generator (e.g. `./generate.py source`)?
- add an `-s` to your generator call (e.g. `./generate.py -s source` - this prints a python stacktrace) and print the output here
- run `./generate.py info` and print the output here
- validate your `config.json` if it's valid JSON via [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) => You should get: `JSON: good.`

Comment: My bad. I was running `generator.py` from the qooxdoo distribution instead of `generate.py` from the root directory of my project.